# Empty list not detected in scala

Tags: scala, rest, playframework-2.1

In my REST API Controller, I receive a list of strings, if the input list is empty i should return bad request.
The problem is the input is empty, the list contains no items, but the check:

```
if(productIdsList.isEmpty)
```

Return false.

How could that be ??

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not empty, it contains an empty String.

Seems like Eclipse shows and empty String as an empty value (and not as `""` in Scala REPL) and this is confusing.
Try debugging this, it looks exactly the same.

```
object A extends Application {
  val a = List("")
  //any other code here
}
```

The empty list is `Nil` and it looks exactly like `productIdsList.tl` in your debug view

Comment: How empty list appear ?